# Swift opposite to "required", or factory design pattern with required init methods in superclass

Tags: ios, swift, subclass, factory-pattern, superclass

Prefacing a method with `required` makes it so that all subclasses must implement this method. Is there a way to do the opposite: prevent a method in the superclass from being called on an object of the subclass? `forbidden`?

As I'm writing this I'm starting to realize that might actually not be a good idea... Since the conceptual idea of a subclass is that it contains all the data in the superclass, and then some. Theory-wise, if I need to restrict access to a superclass method, that means I'm probably doing it wrong.

What I'm trying to do is write an `init` method for a subclass of UIButton. I want this custom `init` method to be the only way you can create an object of the subclass. But the UIButton (superclass) `init` methods are public and required, so I can't just slap a `private` on them and write myself a factory... But I don't want developers using this class to keep trying every `init` function until they find the one that doesn't crash. I want it to be clear that this is the method to use.

So... Is there functionality in Swift to explicitly prevent access to a superclass method? And either way, what's the "correct" way to implement something like this, without a subclass that restricts access to superclass functionality?

Comment: i think, the only way is encapsulation. this way you can isolate all functionality of your 'superclass', which is now your private property and not your superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to call the method by yourself you can use `@available(*, unavailable, message="Use XYZ instead")`. Swift will prevent anyone from using the method then. It can still be used if you cast the object to a superclass where the method is still available.

Like `sizeThatFits(_:)` in this example: https://github.com/fluidsonic/JetPack/blob/master/Sources/ui/View.swift#L341